# Criar documento WORD de dados com Java - Genexus 9.0

Tags: genexus

Estou com uma aplicação Genexus 9.0 VFP WIN e tenho que converter para Genexus 9.0 JAVA WEB.
Tenho no sistema com VFP WIN funcionando perfeitamente onde é gerado um arquivo .DOC e através de comandos dbase Exemplo:

```
dbase obj.ActiveDocument.MailMerge.Fields.Add(obj.Selection.Range, gx_msg)
dbase obj.Selection.TypeParagraph)
dbase obj.Selection.MoveRight(12)
```

É gerado um documento e abre este documento em formato de visão de dados no WORD.

Alguém pode me dizer se existe os mesmos comando equivalentes em java?
Ou posso criar uma rotina externa em JAVA para fazer este processo?

Answer (score 0):

Eduardo,

Acredito que a melhor alternativa seja começar a utilizar os tipos de dados WordDocument, que são nativos e suportados pela GeneXus.

Podes obter mais informações nesse link:
http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?2101,Generating+Excel+and+Word+Documents,

Comment: Bom dia Sandro, tudo bem?
Já tentei, o problema é que estou usando Genexus 9.0 java WEB e pelo que andei consultando não funciona. Vi várias pessoas reclamando.
Eu estou fazendo uma conversão do GX 9.0 VFP WEB para GX 9.0 Java WEB e tenho várias rotinas paradas por causa deste problema.
Por isso estava pensando fazer alguma coisa por fora.

Comment: Eduardo, não há restrição alguma quanto a ser web, exceto pelos componentes que provavelmente terá que botar na pasta lib do tomcat... 
Já fizemos isso em projetos, mas como faz algum tempo, não lembro exatamente quais são, mas sim, é possível...

Mais informações: https://www.genexus.com/developers/websac?en,,,18847;;

Comment: Muito obrigado.

Comment: Se a resposta foi satisfatória, agradeço se puder votá-la para que outras pessoas que tenham a mesma dúvida possam ser ajudadas.